# Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook and MissingIDFieldWarning

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, anaconda3

I have already intalled Anaconda 3.When I run Jupyter Notebook and save something. The next problem appears:

1. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat_*init*_.py:128: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.
   validate(nb)
2. C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py:353: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.
   validate_nb(model['content'])
   [I 23:27:05.005 NotebookApp] Starting buffering for 956f2cf8-4baa-4f41-a715-89fc3e1b078c:7228c4b40f9241eb968ac5f8c1af

where python -->
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\Mitko Stoychev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\Mitko Stoychev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

where jupyter
(base) --> C:\Users\Mitko Stoychev>where jupyter
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what your question was, so I will explain this warning and how to fix it.

For whatever reason, one of your cells is "missing an id field", which for now produces a `MissingIDFieldWarning`, but "will become a hard error in future nbformat versions".
You can open the Jupyter notebook in question in a text editor, where you should see an `id` field for each cell, e.g.:

```json
"cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,   
   "id": "0945defe",
   ...},
...]
```

Apparently this field was missing for (at least) one of the cells, even though it is a mandatory field and should be produced automatically.

The warning you got already includes a suggestion on how to fix this problem:

```py
import nbformat

with open("problematic_notebook.ipynb", "r") as file:
    nb_corrupted = nbformat.reader.read(file)

nbformat.validator.validate(nb_corrupted)
# <stdin>:1: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, 
# this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. 
# You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). 
# Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.

nb_fixed = nbformat.validator.normalize(nb_corrupted)
nbformat.validator.validate(nb_fixed[1])
# Produces no warnings or errors.

with open("fixed_notebook.ipynb", "w") as file:
    nbformat.write(nb_fixed[1], file)
```